# Show a ProgressBar while uploading a picture (Windows Form C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a situation here. I have a picture box in windows form and i let user to browse a picture by using openfileupload control and after that i set selected picture into picture box. Here is my code:

```
namespace Employee_Card_Manager
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string Chosen_File = "";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selectpic.Title = "Browse Employee Picture!";
        selectpic.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        selectpic.FileName = "";
        selectpic.Filter = "JPEG Images|*.jpg|GIF Images|*.gif|BITMAPS|*.bmp";

        if (selectpic.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            progressBar1.Enabled = true;
            Chosen_File = selectpic.FileName;
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Chosen_File);
            progressBar1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

It is working perfectly! I need to add some modification to this code so that when user browse a picture and presses Open button my application will show him a progress bar that this picture is being uploaded in mean time...
I have found the following code to show a progress bar:

```
namespace ProgressBarSampleCSharp
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CreateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressBar pBar = new ProgressBar();
        pBar.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 20);
        pBar.Name = "progressBar1";
        pBar.Width = 200;
        pBar.Height = 30;

        //pBar.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;

        pBar.Minimum = 0;
        pBar.Maximum = 100;
        pBar.Value = 70;

        Controls.Add(pBar);
    }
}
```

}

But i have no idea how to fit this code into my class so that it will show progress bar in the mean time when picture is being uploaded!
any ideas??

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean with 'uploaded'. I understand the act of upload as something sent over the wire to a remote location. Do you mean 'load the image into the picture box'?

Comment: How long does it take to show the image in the PictureBox? I'm surprised that would even require a progress bar.

Comment: @Steve yes i definitely mean that load the image into the picture box.

Comment: @SuperOli I know it does take few seconds to upload picture into picture box but i am trying to let user know that something is going on within that few seconds...

Answer (score 0):

I have an old code adapted to answer your question.
I let the ProgressBar control out of the InitializeComponent just for clarity.
However, I think that when you run this code, you'll remove the progress bar completely.

```
namespace Employee_Card_Manager 
{ 
    public partial class Form1 : Form 
    { 
        ProgressBar pBar = new ProgressBar(); 
        string Chosen_File = ""; 

        public Form1() 
        { 
            InitializeComponent(); 
            CreateProgressBar();
        } 
        private void CreateProgressBar() 
        { 
            pBar.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 20); 
            pBar.Name = "progressBar1"; 
            pBar.Width = 200; 
            pBar.Height = 30; 
            pBar.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            pBar.Minimum = 0; 
            pBar.Maximum = 100; 
            pBar.Value = 0; 
            Controls.Add(pBar); 
        } 

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            selectpic.Title = "Browse Employee Picture!"; 
            selectpic.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); 
            selectpic.FileName = ""; 
            selectpic.Filter = "JPEG Images|*.jpg|GIF Images|*.gif|BITMAPS|*.bmp"; 

            if (selectpic.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel) 
            { 
                Chosen_File = selectpic.FileName; 
                pictureBox1.LoadCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(pictureBox1_LoadCompleted);
                pictureBox1.LoadProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(pictureBox1_LoadProgressChanged);
                pictureBox1.WaitOnLoad = false;
                pictureBox1.LoadAsynch(Chosen_file);
            } 
        } 

        private void pictureBox1_LoadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            pBar.Value = 0;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_LoadProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            pBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: When i added this code and run the project, nothing happens!!
even GUI won't appear.
Plus it gives me syntax error on calling method LoadAsynch(Chosen_File);

Comment: Sorry, typed manually.  Remove 'h' from LoadAsync. For GUI, I don't know. Are you starting your project from a Main method and calling this form1? Also, the namespace in my example is not the same of your second example. Also I don't have posted the designer.cs. Suppose you have it.

Comment: I noticed that when I comment out following line, the GUI runs, otherwise not! 
CreateProgressBar();
It seems to have some problem in this method... There is no main method i can see, Its a Windows Form and i run it using Ctrl+F5!

Comment: All right, I see, so remove the call to create the progress bar as well the declaration of pBar and the method, then create one yourself with Form Designer. Name the progressbar as 'pBar'

Answer (score -2):

If it truly is taking a long time to 'upload' you could use the FileSystemWatcher's changed [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed.aspx). Every time it is fired you increment the progressbar some fraction of the total known file size.