# I want to show file upload progress in c# application

Tags: c#, database

I want to show a file upload progress in c# windows application As I am using online database it takes a bit more time to save or upload.I am using following Code.I have searched but It does not shows exact percent wise progress.Also I Want to change file name before moving to another lOcation.
Thanks In advance.

```
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

        DialogResult dlgRes = dlg.ShowDialog();


        Application.DoEvents();
        label14.Visible = true;
        if (DialogResult.OK != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {

            foreach (string file in dlg.FileNames)
            {
                try
                {
                    newpath = Path.Combine(textBox2.Text, Path.GetFileName(file)).ToString();
                    filenametemp = "tush" + Path.GetFileName(file).ToString();
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("please select folder to save");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(textBox2.Text, Path.GetFileName(file)).ToString());


                        if (dlgRes != DialogResult.Cancel)
                        {
                            //Provide file path in txtFilePath text box.
                            txtFilePath.Text = dlg.FileName;
                        }
                        //string folderpath = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.FullName + textBox2.Text;
                        //string filePath = textBox2.Text + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dlg.FileName);
                        //System.IO.File.Copy(dlg.FileName, folderpath, true);

                        try
                        {
                            //Read File Bytes into a byte array
                            byte[] FileData = ReadFile(txtFilePath.Text);

                            //Initialize SQL Server Connection
                            SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Copymanagment"].ConnectionString);

                            //Set insert query
                            string qry = "insert into fileinfo (File_Id,File_Path,date,OriginalPath,Billnumber,Billdate,FileData) values(@FileId,@Filepath,@Date,@OriginalPath,@Billnumber,@Billdate,@FileData)";

                            //Initialize SqlCommand object for insert.
                            SqlCommand SqlCom = new SqlCommand(qry, CN);




                            string path = textBox2.Text;
                            string[] arrpath = null;
                            int count;
                            arrpath = path.Split('\\');
                            for (count = 0; count <= arrpath.Length - 1; count++)
                            {
                                // MessageBox.Show(arrpath[count]);
                            }
                            string folder = arrpath[arrpath.Length - 1] + databaseid().ToString();

                            //We are passing Original File Path and File byte data as sql parameters.
                            string fileid = Path.GetDirectoryName(dlg.FileName);
                            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileId", (object)folder));
                            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Filepath", (object)newpath));
                            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date", (object)System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")));
                            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OriginalPath", (object)txtFilePath.Text));
                            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Billnumber", (object)textbillno.Text));
                            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Billdate", (object)dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")));
                            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileData", (object)FileData));

                            //Open connection and execute insert query.
                            CN.Open();
                            SqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            CN.Close();
                           label14.Visible = false;
                            //Close form and return to list or Files.
                            MessageBox.Show("File saved Succsesfully");
                            txtFilePath.Text = "";

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File already available");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: do u want to show progress png or u want to show percentage of file uploaded?

Comment: percentage of file uploaded

Comment: Are u willing to use third party controls?

Comment: Yes if any third party control will do my work.

Comment: @Alex There is no need for third party controls.

Comment: @Tarik how can we track how much is the file got uploaded?

Comment: @Alex  I assume "c# windows application" means "winform application". Tushar aws, please confirm.

Comment: @ alex & @ tarik its c# windows application.winform application.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it done, a single statement in inserting the whole data in one shot and blocks until done without a chance to update tge UI. You can upload your BLOB data in chuncks using UPDATETEXT. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3517w44b(v=vs.100).aspx for full explanations on how to do that. Doing that, you will have the opportunity to update the value of a prigress bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp.net ajax control toolkit. There is a ajax file upload control.

**Note** Do not get confused with asynFile upload control in the same library(that control does not have progress bar).

You can get info here http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/AjaxFileUpload-example-to-upload-multiple-files-in

To download the library go here http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/3-Different-ways-to-add-AjaxControlToolkit-in-Asp

for windows app try following https://stackoverflow.com/a/9446524/4810628

Comment: Sir I mentioned c# windows application.